# HTTPS request in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that requires to do some API calls to my secure server.

I'm testing this locally first, with my own created ssl certificates.

My problem is that when i try to do an API call to my server (https://:9000/api/project) i get an error saying: `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.

The weird thing is that i can perfectly do that POST call from other REST clients with no problem, so i know the issue is in the code of the chrome extension.

The xhr request is being done in the background.js script like this:

```
var sendProject = function(projectData) {
        var openhuntURL = 'https://<mylocal>:9000/api/project';
        xhr.open('POST', openhuntURL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                callback(true);
            }
            else {
                callback(false);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(projectData);
    };
```

I don't know what i should do to allow the extension to make that request.

By the way, just before that api call i make another api call to another website and it works just fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You most probably are not using a signed certificate in your local https application, and the browser won't like that at all.

Comment: You mean in the client side? How can i use it? @Havenard

Comment: Yeah. Just try `https://<mylocal>:9000/api/project` directly in the client and see what the browser says.

Comment: It complains about the certificate :S, so basically i can't use a self signed one for testing?

Comment: You can add your self signed certificate as trusted at the OS level and then the warning should go away.

Comment: @abraham, you should add this as an answer so the asker can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and comes to know that there is no such way you can override self signed certificate.

Comment: Actually you can tell chrome to accept your own self signed certificates, you need to import them in your keychain (OSX) and export it, then you actually can import it in chrome and it starts working

Comment: But when you try to send an ajax request to a Test Web Server, you some how need to ignore self signed certificate with chrome extension.
So even importing the certificate in your trusted root won't work here.